# How to make promise resolve before returning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a question about some code that I have. I'm going to post code and break it down below in a second, however i'd like to explain it in advance. My code is a function called getPing, its in a node server and its goes to a website and give me back an array of objects. It sorts through those objects, and based on the lowest number (ping) It pushes them into an array. Once everything is finished, it will sort through the array and pick a random object. That object as you will see in the code is called `selectedserver`, it then takes that object and then it **SHOULD** resolve it, and send the data back to the client. Note that all of this is happening in the same file.

As you will see in a second, once a certain condition is met there is a return, but right above that there is a `resolve()` that I can't seem to get working. Here is my code.

First, we'll start with where the promise starts.

```
var getPing = function (id,index) {

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    var keepAliveAgent = new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true })

    options.agent = keepAliveAgent

    index = index || 0;

    var r = https.request(options, function (res) {

        var data = []
        res.on('data', function (d) {
            data.push(d)
        }).on('end', function () {
            var buf = Buffer.concat(data)
            var encodingheader = res.headers['content-encoding']
            if (encodingheader == 'gzip') {

                zlib.gunzip(buf, function (err, buffer) {
                    var o = JSON.parse(buffer.toString())
                    // o is what is returned

                    if (o.TotalCollectionSize - 20 <= index) {
                        console.log(o.TotalCollectionSize - 20, '<=', index)
                        var selectedserver = games.gameservers[Math.floor(Math.random() * games.gameservers.length)]
                        console.log(selectedserver)
                        resolve(selectedserver)
                        return;
                    }

                    if (index < o.TotalCollectionSize) {
                        index = index + 10;
                        console.log(index, o.TotalCollectionSize)
                        o.Collection.sort(function (a, b) {
                            return a.Ping > b.Ping
                        })

                        if (typeof (o.Collection[0]) != "undefined") {
                            var playerscapacity = o.Collection[0].PlayersCapacity.charAt(0)
                            if (playerscapacity != o.Collection[0].Capacity) {
                                games.gameservers.push(o.Collection[0])
                            }
                        }
                        getPing(id, index)
                    }

                })
            }
        })
    })

    r.end()
    //reject('end of here')
})}
```

As you can see here:

```
if (o.TotalCollectionSize - 20 <= index) {
        console.log(o.TotalCollectionSize - 20, '<=', index)
        var selectedserver = games.gameservers[Math.floor(Math.random() * games.gameservers.length)]
        console.log(selectedserver)
        resolve(selectedserver)
        return;
    }
```

Once the o.Totalcollectionsize - 20 is <= to the index, Its suppose to take the games that it pushed into the games.gameservers array, and its suppose to resolve it. The code works besides the resolve part, I know this because all of the console.log's in that code work.

Now this is my node server, that's supposed to send the resolved data BACK to the client.

```
var server = io.listen(47999).sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
var ip = socket.handshake.address;
var sid = socket.id;
console.log("Connection from " + ip + "\n\tID: " + sid);

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With")
    //res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    var data = []
    if (req.method == "POST") {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        req.on('data', function (dat) {
            data.push(dat)
        })
        req.on('end', function () {
            var gamedata = Buffer.concat(data).toString();
            var game = JSON.parse(gamedata)

            getPing(game.placeId, 0).then(function (r) {
                console.log(r)
                res.end(JSON.stringify(r))
            }).catch(function (e) {
                console.log(e)
            })
            console.log(game.placeId)
        })
    }
}).listen(6157)
console.log('server running')})
```

As you can see, in my node server when you send a post request to it, it will start the promise.

```
getPing(game.placeId, 0).then(function (r) {
            console.log(r)
            res.end(JSON.stringify(r))
        }).catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e)
        })
```

However, it never gets to this point. I'm new to promises so I'm not where I'm going wrong here. I've tried everything (or so i thought). I would like to learn how promises fully work, because clearly I don't understand them enough. I'm just trying to get this to work at this point.

Comment: `getPing()` has several routes within it which result in neither `resolve()` nor `reject()` being called, hence the returned promise may never settle; it may remain pending. For each `if() {...}` you need to provide an `else {...}` clause, in which appropriate action is taken, in particular resolving with some default value, or rejecting with `Error('some suitable error message')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const https = require('https');
const zlib = require("zlib");

function downloadPage(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     https.get(url,(res)=>{
         let raw = "";
         let gunzip = res.pipe(zlib.createGunzip());
         gunzip.on('data',(chunk)=>{
             raw += chunk;
         })
         .on('end',()=>{
             resolve(raw);
         })
         .on('error',(err)=>{
             reject(err);
         })

     })
    });
}

async function myBackEndLogic() {
        const html = await downloadPage('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?page=1&pagesize=2&order=desc&sort=relevance&intitle=javascript%2Bfilter&site=stackoverflow')
        return html;
}

myBackEndLogic().then((data)=>console.log(data));
```

Try something like this.

Comment: Please describe, what did you change and why, to help others identify the problem, and understand this answer.